# Solving 2 simultaneous equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, index-notation

Find the value of x and y .The complete question can be found below.

```
Find the value of x and y which satisfy the simultaneous equation if:

8ˣ/128 = 1/4ʸ  
And
49ˣ/7ʸ = 1
```

so I tried to "eliminate" variable (1) by substituting that variable into (2) with multiplying (1) with 2 and (2) with 3

and I got these
(-4y X 14 = 6x) - (3y = 6x) =  -7y X (-14-3y) = 0
and y = 0

Can you tell me what is my mistake and how to solve this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second equation you can write $49^x$ as $7^{2x}$, and then $\frac{7^{2x}}{7^y}=1$. Now rewrite this equality as $7^{2x-y}=1$. What should $2x-y$ be equal to so that the equation is solved? You can do the same for the first equation , write everything as a power of $2$ , then you get two equations for $x$ and $y$. I assume you can solve it yourself from here.

Comment: Thank you for answering and explaining my question. But, I have some question here.
As you told me, the equality from the first equation is 2x−y = 1 and I can do the same for the first equation and I got 3x-7= -2y. Then, I need to "eliminate" the equation by (2x-y =1) - (3x-7= -2y). Should I convert the equation (1) into 2x-1= y so I can eliminate them?

Comment: well , of course you can but in order to eliminate the $y$ you need to multiply the first euqation with an appropriate scalar , in this case $2$ and then subtract the first equation from the second one, so that you only have terms of $x$ left. Another way of solving this equations would be to write $x$ from the first euqation in terms of $y$ and then plug it in the second one so the second one is just an equation in terms of $y$.